# React .fetch REST call returns empty list in render, but knows the fields of the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

The code is hitting my endpoint, and I have received errors that indicate that it is aware of the elements inside of the list. However, the list returns a size of zero. I'm wondering if I'm passing around the state of the array incorrectly, thus why it's empty by the time I try to render it? I'm a bit of a noob to ReactJS, so excuse the silly question.

Below is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     error: null,
     isLoaded: false,
     items: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
     fetch("http://localhost:8080/retrieve/123")
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(
      (res) => {

        this.setState({

          isLoaded: true,
          items: Array.from(res)
          });
       },
        (error) => {
           this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           error
         });
      }
    )
  }

 render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items} = this.state;
    if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
    return (
    // <ul> 
    //   {items.map(item => (
    //     <li key={item.name}>
    //       {item.name} {item.price}
    //     </li>
    //   ))}
    // </ul> 
       <div>
        test{this.items},
        {items.length}
       </div>

     );
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <MyComponent />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The items.length in the render returns a 0 and 'test' prints as well. CORS is enabled.

thank you

Comment: for starters how long is array you set state with in fetch callback? And what exactly does structure of `res` look like?

Comment: @charlietfl res is a pretty big map of maps being returned as json. I would say about 10 maps inside the main map and then a couple maps inside the 2nd level maps. I just want to return the entire thing right now.

Comment: What does `res.length` return? Hard to help with something we can't see

Comment: Place `console.log(res)` inside `fetch` callback and post its output in the question

Comment: @hindmost No matter where I put console.log(res) inside of componenetDidMount or fetch i get `Line 16:  'res' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: _'res' is not defined..._ This obviously mean the response is empty or not JSON.

Comment: @hindmost on the java side, under the API call should I be returning a map parsed to a json object (doesn't seem to work) or will returning it as an object work fine?